# How to convert string(WYSIWYG) to raw html by using JavaScript Lib?

Tags: javascript, jquery, edit-in-place

I'm using http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable (jEditable JS Lib) in my Rails app's project and i found problems then trying to use about "Usage with Textile, Markdown".
The problems is i could't use .php file into Rails project. Any solution for solving this case?

=> For more understanding what i what

- http://www.textism.com/tools/textile/
- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html (On 'Textile renderer' and try to type in field and press enter or write html tag such as < h r > or < b > or etc,. and then submit you will see like (WYSIWYG).

How to convert string(WYSIWYG) with new line become to raw html?

Example :

```
one
two
three
four
```

Output :

```
one<br>
two<br>
three<br>
four<br>
```

Is any JavaScript library to solve this? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem is, that after you store dynamically uploaded html code, rails sends you that back as escaped data. You can use the `raw` method to display some source ( with you trust in 100% ).

```
<%= raw some_variable %>
```